# When I view a page that contains YoutubePlayerController, the next page stops working

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube, flutter-web

### Problem

The widget on the next page after loading YoutubePlayerIFrame will not work.

For example, suppose you I have A and B Stateful Widgets.
First A is loaded, where `YoutubePlayerIFrame` is called.
You can press the button in A, but when you move to B, the screen freezes there.

I think this is the cause of [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe), but page transitions may be cause, so I will write the details.

### Detail

I’m developing web app using [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe).
I wrote the following YoutubePlayerIFrame in **A** StatefulWidget.

```
        YoutubePlayerIFrame(
          controller: YoutubePlayerController(
            initialVideoId: "NVzIALG7CUc",
            params: YoutubePlayerParams(
              showVideoAnnotations: false,
              autoPlay: false,
              startAt: Duration(seconds: 0),
              showControls: true,
              showFullscreenButton: false,
            ),
          ),
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        ),
```

Video has displayed correctly.

### Page transition

Loading other pages with this code;

```
runApp(MaterialApp(
 onGenerateRoute: (settings){
  Widget wid = Home();
   switch(settings.name){
     case ...........
   }

   return PageRouteBuilder(
    settings: settings,
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => wid,
            transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) =>
                FadeTransition(opacity: a, child: c));
)
```

Then call this;

```
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/' + path);
```

---

When I remove `YoutubePlayerIFrame` from code, it works.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up to use youtube_player_iframe.

So I decided to show YouTube video with [webviewx](https://pub.dev/packages/webviewx).
This works better so far.

Comment: How to show youtube video in webviewx?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not correct** but when I do this, it works better.

Just paste `YoutubePlayerIFrame()` in all pages.

Still need answer...