# Is there other way to show YouTube video for web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm currently using [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe) to show YouTube video.
I could show YouTube vids but this have an issue.

The issue is this; [When I view a page that contains YoutubePlayerController, the next page stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69570949/when-i-view-a-page-that-contains-youtubeplayercontroller-the-next-page-stops-wo)

Now, I gave up to use this. So I'm looking for other way.
I searched but I could find only solution for iOS/Android or using youtube_player_iframe.

Comment: I asked something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68300558/10157127) ,  then while my UI priority was to have smooth scroll, I stopped playing on page-site.  Another way but not solution could be hosting video on different site and playing video with `video_player`.

Comment: thank you. But I don't want to try this. Hosting videos can be expensive. YouTube and Flutter belong to Google, but why is it so annoying? XD

Comment: Due to security restrictions with cross-origin iframe as much as I know. Hope they will resolve it soon.